# Aberrant data reading COM port in windows

Tags: winapi, com-port

From an arduino type microcontroller, the following code sends 16 bit unsigned data over a serial port as raw bytes.

```
void sendTestData() {
    uint16_t *p16 = &bufferp[DATASTART];
    Serial.println( "TESTDATA" );
    for ( int n = 0; n < NPIXELS; n++ ) {
       p16[n] = n;
    }

    Serial.print( "BINARY16 " );
    Serial.println( NPIXELS );
    Serial.write( (byte *) p16, 2*NPIXELS );
    Serial.println( "END DATA" );
}
```

On a Linux host computer, the data is read by the following python code, and everything is okay.  The data is exactly as sent, the values count from 0 to the value of NPIXELS-1.

```
data = self.ser.read( ndata*2 )
data = struct.unpack( '<%dH'%(len(data)/2), data )
data = np.array(data)
```

Now the question/mystery:

On a windows machine (Win11 in vbox), the data is read with the following code.

```
int readBuffer( void *buffer, DWORD nbytes) 
{
    DWORD nread = 0;
    ReadFile(hSerial,buffer,nbytes,&nread, NULL);
    return nread;
}

if ((nread=readBuffer( rawbuffer, nbytes)))
{
    n = 0;
    m = 0;
    while( n<npixels)
    {
        hi = *b++;
        lo = *b++;
        u16 = hi;
        u16 <<= 8;
        u16 |= lo;
        rawbuffer[n++] = u16;
    }
}
```

Scanning the data, we find the following errors.  In the listing, to the right of the color are u16, hi, and lo from the above code.

Notice that the error occurs every 256 U16 words, or every 512 bytes.   In other words it occurs only when the low byte of each reaches 0.  And notice, errors such as the first byte, 0x0A = 0101 rather than 0000,  are not simple sign bit errors.  It looks more like the com port is applying some character coding.

```
aberrant test value at 0 (0x0000): 2560 from read bytes 0x0a 0x00
aberrant test value at 256 (0x0100): 0 from read bytes 0x00 0x00
aberrant test value at 512 (0x0200): 256 from read bytes 0x01 0x00
aberrant test value at 768 (0x0300): 512 from read bytes 0x02 0x00
aberrant test value at 1024 (0x0400): 768 from read bytes 0x03 0x00
aberrant test value at 1280 (0x0500): 1024 from read bytes 0x04 0x00
aberrant test value at 1536 (0x0600): 1280 from read bytes 0x05 0x00
aberrant test value at 1792 (0x0700): 1536 from read bytes 0x06 0x00
aberrant test value at 2048 (0x0800): 1792 from read bytes 0x07 0x00
aberrant test value at 2304 (0x0900): 2048 from read bytes 0x08 0x00
aberrant test value at 2560 (0x0a00): 2304 from read bytes 0x09 0x00
aberrant test value at 2816 (0x0b00): 2560 from read bytes 0x0a 0x00
aberrant test value at 3072 (0x0c00): 2816 from read bytes 0x0b 0x00
aberrant test value at 3328 (0x0d00): 3072 from read bytes 0x0c 0x00
aberrant test value at 3584 (0x0e00): 3328 from read bytes 0x0d 0x00
```

Here is how the com port is opened:

```
bool opencomport(const char *name)
{
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 100, //interval timeout. 0 = not used
                              0, // read multiplier
                             100, // read constant (milliseconds)
                              0, // Write multiplier
                              0  // Write Constant
                            };


    bool retv;

    hSerial = CreateFile(name,
                         GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                         0,
                         0,
                         OPEN_EXISTING,
                         FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                         0);

    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        MessageBox(NULL,"failed to open comport","",MB_OK);
        exit(-1);
    }

    if ( !SetupComm(hSerial,2*16384,4096) ) {
        MessageBox(NULL,"failed to allocate serial port buffers","",MB_OK);
        exit(-1);
    }

    set8bit();

    if (!SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts)) {
        MessageBox(NULL,"failed to set timeouts","",MB_OK);
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    getcomportbuffersizes();

    return true;
}
```

So, what is wrong?   The data is good in the python code in Linux, the errors appear only in windows.

Comment: Could you reproduce with [putty](https://github.com/github/putty)? Also, could you please show a minimal sample?

Comment: Are you calling `SetCommState()` to configure the serial port? What does that code look like? What does the code look like that is detecting abberant data? What you have provided is not a [mcve]

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT   Since the problem involves communication with an external device, a self contained sample is unfortunately not feasible.  However the firmware for that device is posted on my github, if you want to try it.   As I mentioned, I established that the data is good when read on linux with python.

Comment: @RemyLebeau    The code you see there is everything I am doing to open and configure the comport.  Is there something else that I am missing?   Recall the data is read okay by python on linux.

Comment: Re the request for RME.   IT is not feasible exactly.   But I did post the functions for the send side (teensy or perhaps arduino) and receive side (windows 11) of the communications that produce the error.

Comment: @DrM "*The code you see there is everything I am doing*" - then you are missing quite a lot of settings, such as `SetCommState()` and `SetCommConfig()`, which control various characteristics of how the serial port behaves. Have you read the documentation yet? [Communications Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/communications-resources)

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Thank you, I will take a look.  As it turns out, moving the byte ops tand few other math ops to another source file made it go away.  So, maybe an error n the code or maybe an optimizer feature.

Comment: oops and now it came back, with no change in code.  slowing the transfer rate makes it go away

Comment: @DrM all the more reason to look at your serial port setup.

Comment: Not an API issue, more about encoding and device. You may contact your device manufacture. Generally, microcontrollers have echo mode which you can utilize to troubleshoot.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I agree, and I have looked into the documentation and found nothing suggestive apart from increasing the buffer size, which I did.   Another possibility is that it might be  a "feature" of working in a vbox.   One might guess the host is still handling the port with the linux usb-virtual serial port driver, there the buffer is limited to 4k.  But I have no way to test the hypothesis except to note that it doesn't have issues when it is a dedicated thread doing the reads in software running in the host

Comment: @RemyLebeau  re that previous comment, somebody is testing on actual w11 machine now.

Comment: This still sounds like a config issue to me. Did you verify the serial port's [`DCB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-dcb) settings match what the microcontroller is expecting? That is why you should be calling `SetCommState()` when you open the port. Don't rely on the port having the defaults you are expecting. Set them explicitly. If you still have the problem after that, then something else is going on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Ok, so we confirmed that data loss and corruption occurs on hardware windows 11 platform.  And we added a crc and we we added an synch mode, the device sends ready, the listening thread wakes up and sends "send".     Sending 4KB of binary gives us a very high rate of corrupted packets.   Sending the data as formatted strings, works better, the first frames are often corrupted but then it gets "into the groove".

Comment: @RemyLebeau   Can you suggest a specific C-code to try for the setup?   I am starting to think it might have to do with windows' latency for servicing the port or switching to the thread in the app that does the listening.